# How to Sync my Mail app with my Gmail account?

Tags: mail.app, gmail

I want to start using my Mail app on Mac the same way I use it on my iPhone. On my iPhone once I read an email it is marked as read in my gmail account as well (if I access it from the web) and vice versa, this does not happen with Mail on my Mac.

If I read an email on my iPhone it is still marked as unread on my Mac, and if I read an email on my Mac it is still marked unread on both my gmail (the web interface) and my iphone. Is there a way to sync Mail with my Gmail account properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if Gmail on your Mac is set up to use IMAP instead of POP3 by going to Preferences > Accounts in Mail. IMAP syncs the read / unread status (among a host of other benefits).

If it's not set up to use IMAP then you'll have to remove the account and add it again, this time making sure to select IMAP in the account wizard.

Answer (score 0):

This is the manual you want.
Everything is explained how to configure your mac

External link: https://www.macstories.net/tutorials/how-to-configure-gmail-with-os-x-yosemite-mail/